# Force Emacs to use a particular encoding if and only if that causes no trouble

Tags: emacs, encoding

In my .emacs file, I use the line

```
'(setq coding-system-for-write 'iso-8859-1-unix)
```

to have Emacs save files in the iso-8859-1-unix encoding. When I
enter characters that cannot be encoded that way ("Łódź" for
example), I get prompted to select a different encoding, but upon
entering `iso-8859-1-unix' into the minibuffer, the file is saved and
the offending characters are lost.

If I just hit enter at the prompt, the file is saved in Unicode, and
when I close and reopen Emacs it is interpreted as a Unicode file
again. If I then remove the offending characters, save the file and
close and reopen Emacs another time, it is still interpreted as a
Unicode file -- from which I deduce that it has still been saved in
Unicode, even though saving in iso-8859-1-unix would have been
possible.

So is there a way to force Emacs to write a file in iso-8859-1
whenever possible, and never save it in that encoding if doing so
would gobble characters?

Many thanks in advance,

Thure Dührsen

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc string for `coding-system-for-write`, you should not be setting it globally.

Perhaps what you are looking for is `(prefer-coding-system 'iso-8859-1-unix)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'iso-8859-1)
```

#### Edit:

Incorporating AProgrammer's suggestion, we get

```
(defun enforce-coding-system-priority ()
  (let ((pref (car (coding-system-priority-list)))
        (list (find-coding-systems-region (point-min) (point-max))))
    (when (or (memq 'undecided list) (memq pref list))
      (setq buffer-file-coding-system pref))))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'enforce-coding-system-priority)

(prefer-coding-system 'iso-8859-1)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that gives the exact same behaviour as with

`'(setq coding-system-for-write 'iso-8859-1-unix)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to write a save time hook function which would check the content of the buffer and set the encoding correspondingly.  By using find-coding-system-region there shouldn't be much work.

Answer (score 0):

The following should make Emacs ask when the buffer encoding is *not* that with which emacs is set up to save the file. Emacs will then prompt you to chose one among "safe" encodings.

```
(setq select-safe-coding-system-accept-default-p
      '(lambda (coding)
         (string=
          (coding-system-base coding)
          (coding-system-base buffer-file-coding-system))))
```